# Bot Framework Composer Sending Direct Messages

Tags: botframework, bot-framework-composer

I have a lot of questions about getting started. I currently have a sample bot I built in Composer that works for my teams/slack channels and works in the testing Bot Framework Emulator without issue.

I am not sure how to make the bot send a direct message/private message to a user in a channel instead of it replying directly in the channel itself. Any one have any ideas of how to accomplish this?

Comment: Do you want to `@mention` the user in a channel/group conversation, or do you want to start a new 1:1 conversation between the user and the bot?

Comment: Start a 1x1 conversation between the user and the bot if the user says something like hello in the channel

Answer (score 0):

You can send messages from the bot to any user (or channel) by using the Azure Bot Service REST API (using the Send an HTTP Request action in Composer as described [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/bot-service/rest-api/bot-framework-rest-connector-api-reference?view=azure-bot-service-4.0#create-conversation).  As you'll see in the documentation, the main limitation is that the recipient must have had a previous conversation with your bot from which you've recorded the conversationID (and activityID if you want to reply to a thread).